# Trying to Exclude Sticky Posts From date_query

Tags: wp-query, sticky-post

```
<?php
$lastThirty = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today - 30 days'));
$currentMonth = date('M Y'); 
$t = date('d-m-Y');
$today = date("D",strtotime($t));

$lastThirty = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
          'ignore_sticky_posts' => false,
        array(
            'year'  => $lastThirty,
            'month' => $currentMonth,
            'day'   => $today,

            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        ),
    ),
); ?>

<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query($lastThirty);


?>
```

Comment: Please, add a description of your problem and format the code to be readable.

Comment: Your `date_query` is completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your query, do it this way ( I believe you were missing the 'date_query' key ):

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => 2012,
            'month' => 12,
            'day'   => 12,
        ),
    ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'post__not_in'  => get_option('sticky_posts') ...
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Comment: Please add an explanation to how your code works and how it should be used

Comment: Sure, @PieterGoosen - is that sufficient to explain OP's issue?